# Change a file into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, biopython

Hello everyone I have a file sucha as ;

**ORFs.fa**

```
>scaffold_11404_1 [179 - 301] 
MLLLKKAQCLTREE
>scaffold_11404_38 [5350 - 3194] (REVERSE SENSE) 
MADQKNLQMSRDLALCARHGIPSLFAFLGDIVSTGISQYAISKLMVANLDLSNVDTKLNA
WQTEGGKYYAAEALIRKLDAIDRQMTEPARIACKYGLLVDLRHTLDFATDNMVANARAEV
MLDMRSYHPSNAMLQNNLTRIMVLVKNTPPQSVVSGKQAMRYIPGWQEDLECPMQKYVFF
>scaffold_11404_45 [2557 - 2450] (REVERSE SENSE) 
MCKQGICRHTRHLSHIMFKLWNNFKYQNIKETRISD
>scaffold_11404_46 [2311 - 2436] 
MIFIELKYSSSLKNYNSSKFNIKNLTKLKHQFYLFFYTFFNT
```

and I would need to change it as a dataframe with 5 columns such as :

**ORF_df**

```
Segments          start2 end2     sens    sequence 
scaffold_11404_1   179   301     normal  MLLLKKAQCLTREE
scaffold_11404_38  5350  3194    reverse MADQKNLQMSRDLALCARHGIPSLFAFLGDIVSTGISQYAISKLMVANLDLSNVDTKLNA
WQTEGGKYYAAEALIRKLDAIDRQMTEPARIACKYGLLVDLRHTLDFATDNMVANARAEV
MLDMRSYHPSNAMLQNNLTRIMVLVKNTPPQSVVSGKQAMRYIPGWQEDLECPMQKYVFF
scaffold_11404_45  2557  2450    reverse MCKQGICRHTRHLSHIMFKLWNNFKYQNIKETRISD
scaffold_11404_46  2311  2436    normal  MIFIELKYSSSLKNYNSSKFNIKNLTKLKHQFYLFFYTFFNT
```

does someone have an idea please ?

So far I tried this code, it works but it is to slow...

```
ORF_df=pd.DataFrame(columns=("Segments","start2","end2","sens","sequence"))
with open("ORFs.fa") as fasta_file:  # Will close handle cleanly
          for seq_record in SeqIO.parse(fasta_file, 'fasta'):  # (generator)
              full_name=seq_record.description
              sens=re.sub(".*\(","",full_name)
              if sens == 'REVERSE SENSE)':
                sens="reverse"
              else:
                sens="normal"
              start_end=re.sub(".*\[","",full_name)
              start_end=re.sub("\].*","",start_end)
              start_end=start_end.split("-")
              start=start_end[0]
              end=start_end[1]
              sequence=seq_record.seq
              Segments=seq_record.id
              ORF_df=ORF_df.append({"Segments":re.sub("_[^_]*$","",Segments), "sequence":str(sequence), "start2":start,"end2":end, "sens":sens},ignore_index=True)
              print(ORF_df)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about just parsing the text with slices.

- Use a regular expression to parse records;
- split the record on whitespace;
- extract the relevant info with slices;
- build a dictionary with the info;
- feed the dictionary to the DataFrame *constructor*.

---

```
import pandas as pd
import re

with open("ORFs.fa") as fasta_file:
    s = fasta_file.read()

pat =  r'^>[^>]+'    # pattern to find records

d = {'scaffolding':[],'start':[],'stop':[],'sense':[],'sequence':[]}
for r in re.findall(pat,s,flags=re.M):
    scaf,start,_,stop,*rest = r.split()
    d['scaffolding'].append(scaf[1:])
    d['start'].append(start[1:])
    d['stop'].append(stop[:-1])
    if rest[0][1:] == 'REVERSE':
        sense = 'REVERSE'
        i = 2
    else:
        sense = 'NORMAL'
        i = 0
    d['sense'].append(sense)
    d['sequence'].append(''.join(rest[i:]))

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)
```

---

Relies on:

- the text file being **Uniform**
- no `>` characters except at the start of a record

---

If there are a LOT of records you might want to use re.finditer instead of re.findall.

```
for match in re.finditer(pat,s,flags=re.M):
    scaf,start,_,stop,*rest = match.group().split()
    ...
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much it works like a charm and it is very efficient !

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea use nested split methods
For example first split by '>' that will separate records then split by space  " " that will separate the individual values.
You can go on one step at a time storing desired results in some variable
Also don't create a dataframe first and then append to it. create a dictionary with colum names as keys like this

```
df = {
"Col1 name": [],
"col2 name":[]
}
```

Then append to that list in the dictionary like this

```
df["Col1 name"].append(value)
```

Finally you can create dataframe from this dictionary

```
Csv = pd.DataFrame(df)
```